# What (important) controls are missing from EOS 1000D (w.r.t 5xxD)

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, canon-550d, canon-1000d

I am planning to converge on the Canon EOS 1000D as the camera to purchase. The other considerations were EOS 500D and EOS 550D, but they are much more than what I want to spend right now. (2nd hand purchases are a bit dicey, so I'm not considering some of the other models usually recommended in other threads here).

Would like to know what important controls are missing (or are difficult to access because of no dedicated button) on the 1000D.

I read in one of the threads that metering is one such issue, as it has to be accessed only via the LCD.

Are there any such pain points, due to which I should consider the 500D (which is the next camera in terms of features and price, although at a significant difference).

My target shots are general landscape, potraits, etc. Nothing *very* high speed, or *very high* macro. Planning to get the 18-55 kit + 50mm 1/8 prime, and possible the 18-135 if budget allows.

** Edit **

I have already compared these, and more models, on dpreview and understand the sensor limitations, lack of movie recording, and lower ISO range.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spot metering would be handy, especially for portraits, but you can always take a test shot first and check the histogram.

Wireless remote control is also a nice-to-have, for example setting up a wildlife shot and then retreating from the camera. However you will still have the option of using a cable release.

Also the viewfinder is slightly smaller (0.81x vs 0.87x) on the 1000D but that falls into teh category of 'you get what you pay for'.

Answer (score 1):

As for control, I think they both have the same number of buttons/controls. For a complete comparison you can always use dpreview.com: http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/sidebyside.asp

Here are the main things I can find:

- No high ISO
- No movie capability
- Sub-standard LCD

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the comparisons here as well as on other sites. The points you mention above are all already considered into the decision (you get what you pay for :) )

I was looking for more feedback from people who have used the cameras first hand, and can compare.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know 1000D does not have proximity sensor that turns off the main LCD when you raise the camera to your eye. (One thing I'd really miss when using 1000D is a status LCD, but 550D doesn't have it either so that's a moot point when you're choosing between those two.)